# Cannot connect django container to postgres on a linux host machine

Tags: python, django, linux, postgresql, docker

After going through all of the Stackoverflow threads on this topic, I still could not solve the problem. This happens only on my Fedora laptop, on my Macbook, the docker containers work perfectly fine. My `docker-compose.yml` file is very standard:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    container_name: data-management
    restart: always
    build: ./
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    links:
      - 'postgresdb'
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/local/share/src/app
    env_file:
      - .dev.env

  postgresdb:
    container_name: be-postgres
    restart: always
    image: postgres:12.7-alpine
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - postgres-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .dev.env

volumes:
  postgres-db:
```

As you can see the environment variables are read in both containers from a file:

```
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=devpassword123
POSTGRES_USER=devuser
POSTGRES_SERVICE=postgresdb
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
```

These env variables are also used in the `settings.py`

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': os.environ['POSTGRES_SERVICE'],
        'NAME': os.environ['POSTGRES_USER'],
        'PORT': os.environ['POSTGRES_PORT'],
        'USER': os.environ['POSTGRES_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'],
    }
}
```

The problem that I am having is that the django application cannot connect to the postgresDB:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Host is unreachable
> Is the server running on host "postgresdb" (172.xx.x.x) and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I also checked if the port in the postgres container is opened and it is:

```
/ # netstat -tuplen
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:37009        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:59651        0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

Last, but not least, I pinged the postgres container from the django one and it seems like every thing is ok.

This works fine on my macbook machine, therefor, I assume something is wrong on my Fedora laptop. Something else I noticed, which I also find strange is that the django container builds fine, but when I try to install a package from the container I get an error:

```
/usr/local/share/src/app # apk add gcc
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main: temporary error (try again later)
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main: No such file or directory
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community: temporary error (try again later)
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community: No such file or directory
```

My Linux, docker as well as networking skills are definitely not enough to figure out, why my Fedora laptop is struggling to run this simple setup.

Comment: Seems like it is not seeing the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out Fedora switched to nftables, which does not go well with Docker. The easiest solution was to switch back to iptables - `sudo vim /etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf` and change

```
# FirewallBackend
# Selects the firewall backend implementation.
# Choices are:
#       - nftables (default)
#       - iptables (iptables, ip6tables, ebtables and ipset)
FirewallBackend=iptables
```

See [the accepted answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657545/nftables-whitelisting-docker) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Try and build using flag "--network host". Here is the [Link](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)